# What is the chromatic polynomial for $K_{2,3}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

I'm trying to find the chromatic polynomial of the  $K_{2,3}$

(Here $K_{2,3} $ is the complete Bipartite Graph like the blow.)

[image]

I focused on the two points lying on the above. There are only two cases under the hypothesis we have $x$-colors.

$(1)$ First case) Both of the above points are colored by the same color. $x$ for the above parts(two points parts). Then naturally $(x-1)^3$ for the below part(three points parts)
Hence, $x(x-1)^3$

$(2)$ second case) Each of the above points are colored by differently.  $x(x-1)$ for the above parts(two points parts). Then naturally $(x-2)^3$ for the below part(three points parts). Hence, $x(x-1)(x-2)^3$

So my answer is $x(x-1)^3 + x(x-1)(x-2)^3 $. But the answer was $(x-1)^5+(x-1)^2-x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2 = 
x^4 - 3 x^3 + 3 x^2 - x$ What did I wrong?

Comment: $x^4 - 3 x^3 + 3 x^2 - x$ cannot possibly be correct -- the degree of the chromatic polynomial of a graph always equals the number of vertices.

Comment: Your answer is right and the other answer is wrong. (It's the chromatic polynomial of $K_{1,3}$.) What is your source for the wrong answer? Is it from a textbook?

Comment: @bof, No. In my teaching assistance's note.

Comment: That first term should be $x^2(x-1)^3$, not $x(x-1)^3$.